# I am developing an Android app with ArcGIS offline map support. For that which one I have to use? MPK or MMPK package? How to download it?

Tags: android, arcgis-runtime, esri-maps, arcgis-android-api

I am developing an Android app with **ArcGIS offline map** support. To work with an offline map in android what I have to download? **MPK** or **MMPK**? By which tool I can generate the corresponding package? Does anyone have previous experience on the same? I am using *com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.7.0* dependancy. The documentation are totally confusing for me. We have already purchased a **Development builder starter** license too. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked sample code provided by Esri?

Comment: Yes the example is with MMPK file. Which I already tried. But I dont know how to create offline mmpk with ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to use a map offline.

1. Create a Web Map in ArcGIS Online and take that offline. This does not involve an MMPK.
2. OR: Create a MMPK using ArcGIS Pro (a desktop product for Windows)

I expect you might want to consider option 1?

1. Create and save a web map in ArcGIS Online.
2. In the Settings ensure it's enabled for Offline. You should also ensure the layers you're using are offline enabled.
3. Use the OfflineMapTask to generate and download the offline map.

This is explained [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/guide/take-map-offline-on-demand.htm), but you might also find [this technical session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0DP4c1IbEo&list=PLaPDDLTCmy4Y0GMTl0O4V6LF3EmxIAivv&index=24&t=0s) helpful.

If you need to go the other route of generating an MMPK, you will need ArcGIS Pro.

MPKs are not a format that Runtime supports.

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy :)